# How to POST headers to the url of every page loaded in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, node-webkit

I have been trying to POST headers using

```
$.ajaxSetup{
headers:{"key":"value"}
url: urliframe
}
```

to the url of every page loaded in an iframe by capturing the url with

```
urliframe =  document.getElementById('iframeID').contentWindow.location.href
```

But it is giving me the error of

```
POST about:blank net:: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

And when i log the iframe using

```
console.log(urliframe);
```

I get the right URL of the content in iframe in console.

How do i get the value POSTed right or get the url in KNOWN_URL_SCHEME?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the contents of iframe being served from the same host as the page that contains it?

Comment: Yes. i guess that is why i can see the url when i console.log it. Instead of the urliframe, when i write any specific url i get the headers POSTed. the only problem is the value of location.href captured is not being able to be used to POST.